# Subtracting 1 from a value and storing it in another variable

Tags: php, shorthand, decrement

I vaguely remember running into this problem before, but I'm wondering if this just doesn't work in PHP:

```
echo $counter; // outputs 4
$output = $counter--;
echo $output; // outputs 4
```

If I do something like:

```
$output = $counter - 1;
```

I have no problems whatsoever.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: In `$counter--`. the `--` won't occur until after the expression was performed. it's known as a POST decrement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code, using post-decrement, should be read as:

- set the value of $counter to $output; then
- decrement $counter

What you want is the following (pre-decrement), which says

- decrement $counter; then
- set the value of $counter to $output

The code is:

```
<?php
  $counter = 4;
  echo $counter;
  $output = --$counter;
  echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Crap :) That absolutely makes sense... and actually, I read about that before, but since I never had to use it, forgot it again. Since #4 gets assigned before it is decremented, whatever happens to #3? It decrements to #3 and then just gets lost in cyberspace?

Comment: In the original code, `$output` would have been 4, and `$counter` would have been 3. You just assigned the value to `$output` *before* $counter got decremented.

Comment: the 3 stays in `$counter` variable

Answer (score 11):

What you want is the [pre-decrement operator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

```
echo $counter; // outputs 4
$output = --$counter;
echo $output; // outputs 3
```